# changing the sshd port to 2222 still accept only port 22 ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port

i change the port in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config to Port 2222
[image]
but when i try to login
ssh -p 2222 myuser@hostname_ip
it gives me :
[image]

but when i try with port 22 all working
i did restart the vm after change .
what im missing here ?

Comment: 1. Add in question text, not images. 2. DId you restart `sshd` after editing the config?

Comment: yes did restart

Comment: restart `sshd` and provide `netstat` output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, sshd is controlled by Systemd. This is outlined in the comment in the three lines *above* your Port statement. Reading comments in config files is usually useful, especially when things don't work the way you expect.

If you read the suggested file, it will contain the following snippet:

```
The provided ssh.socket unit file sets ListenStream=22.  If you need to have
it listen on a different address or port, then you will need to do this as
follows (modifying ListenStream to match your requirements):

  mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d
  cat >/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf <<EOF
  [Socket]
  ListenStream=2222
  EOF
  systemctl daemon-reload

See systemd.socket(5) for details.
```

I would perhaps suggest doing that. I would also strongly suggest actually reading documentation.

Comment: i have something strange at work i have this problem , at home same laptop 
all working fine with port 22 the defualt